# Android writes to file fine in emulator but not on actual phone

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app where you input the date, time, location to and from, and any notes you have to track your mileage. In my AddActivity.java, you input the information. A BufferedWriter then writes this information to a txt file. In my EditActivity.java (attached), the text should be automatically read from the file and then displayed to the user in an EditText. When I run it an an emulator, the text displays fine. When I run it on my phone after exporting it, the text "Could not retrieve" displays meaning that the BufferedReader in the try/catch block did not successfully run. What am I missing here? Thanks!

```
    package com.reese.mileagelog;


    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class EditActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button addBut;
Button editBut;
Button emailBut;
EditText editText;
String currentText;
Button delete;
public String current;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    delete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    editText.setText(getCurrentText());
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getCurrentText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.delete:
            deleteText();

            editText.setText(getCurrentText());
            break;

    }
}
public void deleteText(){
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
    try {
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new 
        File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"MileageLog.txt")));
        bufferedWriter.write("");
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getCurrentText()
{
    String currentText ="Could not retrieve";

    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new 
                File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"MileageLog.txt")));
        String read;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");

        while((read = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        builder.append(read);
        }
        currentText = builder.toString();
        editText.setText(currentText);
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return currentText;
}

    }
```

Comment: Capture this as a string and print it to the log so we can see if it is okay.

getFilesDir()+File.separator+"MileageLog.txt"

Comment: I am sorry I have no idea how to use logs. Do I use Log.e, d, v, w, I??

Comment: And do you want the log from inside my phone app or emulator?

Comment: Log.d is fine. Just print the string out any way you can and see if it looks okay. You can print it in a Toast if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without more info, but my best guess is that your app is being installed on the SD card (external storage) and not on the internal one.
When that happens, you need a special permission to write files, which you add in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

If you'd rather avoid this permission, make sure you **don't** have [android:installLocation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install) set to `preferExternal`

Comment: You **always** need the permission to write on the "external storage", even if you are inside the inner storage. If the OP wouldn't set this permission, the app wouldn't work **in the emulator too**.